# Faced issue in installing sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, error, vs-code, lwc-dev-server

i am trying to view component locally in vs code but when i run sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server this command i get error

C:\HelloWorldLightningWebComponen>sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 199.232.45.145:443
Code: ETIMEDOUT

how to rectify this??plz help me out

Comment: Is your internet connection good enough? Or are you working through a proxy?

Comment: i am not working with proxy and my internet connection is fine

Comment: Does it work when you hit the URL https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@salesforce%2flwc-dev-server on the browser directly. See [related post](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/3)